# "?" quantifier being recognized as a parameter when used in a sql posix statement, redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run something similar to the below on a table in redshift

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table t
WHERE     t.pagepath ~ '^www\\.example\\.[a-z\\.]+\\/web(\\/)?(#\\/)?(home.*)?(\\?.*)?$'
```

The pagepath column contains URLs, I am trying to group them based on what part of the site they represent.

the desired result is to get the following URLs and similar

```
www.example.com/web
www.example.com/web/
www.example.it/web/#/home/next/example
www.example.com/web/home/next/example
www.example.com.eu/web?q=searchterm
```

I'm receiving an error that says

> Parameters cannot be used with normal Statement objects, use
>   PreparedStatements instead.

Is the issue the syntax I'm using or is it not possible to use the "?" quantifier on groups?

Let me know if this requires more information.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you are using redshift as i didnt think that ~ was supported?

Comment: Hey @Jon, I believe it is supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html